# Missing state value after function binding in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to React and have some trouble right now.
I have component, which catches some object as props and few functions to change state once at few seconds:

```js
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      variants:   props.variants,
      background: props.variants[0].background
    }
  }
  setTimer () {
    const { variants } = this.state
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.updateBackground.bind(this), 1000)
  }
  updateBackground () {
    console.log(`Keys ${this.state.variants}`);
    const { variants }    = this.state
    const { background }  = variants[parseInt(Math.random() * 5)]
    setState({
      background: background
    }, this.setTimer)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setTimer()
  }
  render() {
    const { background } = this.state
    return (
            <div className="header-image"> <img src={ background } /> </div>
      )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

My problem is: after

```
this.updateBackground.bind(this)
```

call, updateBackground lost all state values, e.g.

```
this.state.variants
```

is defined, but its no more contains objects, e.g

```
this.state.variants[0] === undefined
```

Explain to me please what i doing wrong :)

Comment: It should be `this.setState`

Comment: why don't you use setInterval instead of setTimeout?

Comment: @AndrewLi, problem is earlier, than this.setState, this.state.variants[0].background is undefined

Comment: It doesn't looks like you need to store `variants` in state, you can just use the value from props directly. You should avoid putting props into initial state, and if you do, prefix the props with 'initial' - like "initialVariants": see https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Comment: @vijayst, both variants not working :( But if i set interval, error will shows up every second, instead once

Comment: @TomDavies, anyway, directly from this.props or this.state its not working

Comment: Is the initial state / background coming alright?

Comment: @NikitaGoncharov - can you add in the code that calls your component to the question? I'm expecting something like `<Header variants={['abc.jpg', ...]} />`? That should help people rule out the props not being passed in correctly.

Comment: @vijayst yes, background exists, and in function of timer, i log keys of variants and it shows it all, but in updateBackground its show empty array

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing a little bit here. The variants in props maybe empty initially. If the props are going to change, set state in componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.variants !== this.props.variants) {
    this.setState({ variants: nextProps.variants });
  }
}
```

The other option is what Tom Davies suggested. Use the props directly.

```
  updateBackground () {
    const { variants }    = this.props
    const { background }  = variants[parseInt(Math.random() * 5)]
    this.setState({
      background
    }, this.setTimer);
  }
```

Comment: The problem is what component recieved props, i check this in setTimer function, but when i call from setTimer function updateBackground, it dont have props values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(this.updateBackground.bind(this), 1000)
```

When you call `setTimeout`, the very moment you bind it, you lost the scope of the class. Try this

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      variants:   props.variants,
      background: props.variants[0].background
    }
    this.updateBackground = this.updateBackground.bind(this)
  }
```

And

```
this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.updateBackground(), 1000)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution dont help me ;(

Comment: Even if you try to pass props and state as parameter to your function? `setTimeout(() => this.updateBackground(state, props), 1000)`. Of course you have to extract them

Answer (score 0):

You can make quite a few changes to improve the readability and maintainability of your component. I've assumed that it should update every 1000ms and so swapped to use `setInterval` instead to avoid having to keep resetting the timer - since updating the image is not a long running operation anyway.

Additionally, I've added handling for when the component unmounts to stop the interval/timer from continuing to try and run and act on a component that is no longer there.

**Component**

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // We can just use props, don't need to copy variants
        // into state since it's never changed.
        this.state = {
            currentBackground: props.variants[0].background,
            intervalId: null
        };

        // I'll bind everything in the constructor, so it's
        // only done once and removes clutter from methods.
        this.updateBackground = this.updateBackground.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Do everything we need to on startup here, since it's only
        // setting the update interval, won't break it out into
        // separate functions.
        this.setState({
            intervalId: setInterval(() => this.updateBackground(), 1000)
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // When the component is unmounted, stop the interval.
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }

    updateBackground() {
        // Assuming you wanted a whole number here, in which case
        // floor() makes more sense than parseInt(). We should use
        // variants.length rather than assuming there are 5 entries.
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.variants.length);

        this.setState({
            currentBackground: this.props.variants[index].background
        })
    }

    render() {
        // Somewhat opinionated, but there doesn't seem to be any reason
        // to wrap this in a <div>. You could then rename this component
        // and reuse it anywhere you wanted a random image.
        return <img className="header" src={this.state.currentBackground} />;
    }
}

Header.propTypes = {
    variants: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

**Called like...**

```
<Header variants={[{ background: 'abc.png' }, { background: 'def.png' }]} />
```

Comment: I am use your code and get same error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'background' of undefined"

Comment: @NikitaGoncharov, there was a typo in the propTypes declaration (fixed now if you want to try again) - that wouldn't have caused the issue you described though. It sounds like maybe you're passing an array of strings in, rather than objects? What does render() look like in the component you're using Header in?