# Cannot bind context values to setInterval function Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have to say, that i searching for answer in hours and nothing helped me, so here my problem:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var self = this
  console.log(`INIT keys ${this.props.variants}`); // INIT KEYS [Object], [Object] ...
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(`Keys ${self.props.variants}`); // Keys ...
  }.bind(self), 1000)
}
```

Init keys exists, but keys inside interval not.
Can someone help me? :)

Comment: A lot can happen in 1,000ms. It's not a big surprise that the object has changed one second later, but this small bit of code doesn't give us enough to venture a guess as to why.

Comment: Is `self`defined ? Shouldn't you use `this` inside of your function instead of `self`?

Comment: @Ksyqo, OP isn't using `this` inside the callback (but uses `self`), so an arrow function wouldn't help here.

Comment: I believe your problem is in using self inside interval function. Try console.log(`Keys ${this.props.variants}`); instead

Comment: @JordanRunning thanks! Its definetly my fault, something is happen with my array of objects. For now i look for a trouble in another place, thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing state value after function binding in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307901/missing-state-value-after-function-binding-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

In your `setInterval` bound, you will have to use `this` and not `self`. Also, you don't need to redeclare `this`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(`INIT keys ${this.props.variants}`);
  this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(`Keys ${this.props.variants}`);
  }.bind(this), 1000)
}
```

---

If you can use arrow functions, you can ignore the bind as an arrow function doesn't redeclare `this`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(`INIT keys ${this.props.variants}`);
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(`Keys ${this.props.variants}`);
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was really helpful. I had a similar issue